# Formatting of my images goes crazy when I make them hyperlinks

Tags: html, css, anchor

Looking for suggestions as to why my social icons are doing this. Haven't had this issue before. I am assuming that some other css is affect it but I cannot find it anywhere.

I do *not* want the formatting of these images to change when they are links and would wish.

I'm sure there is a simple quick fix....gutted I'm missing it and thanks for taking a look at this.

```
<div id = "socialcontainer">
    <A HREF = ""><IMG class = "socials" SRC = "icons/FB.png"></IMG></A>
    ><IMG class = "socials" SRC = "icons/insta.png">
    <IMG class = "socials" SRC = "icons/SC.png">
    <IMG class = "socials" SRC = "icons/YT.png">
    <IMG class = "socials" SRC = "icons/BIT.png">
  </div><!--socialcontainer -->

    #socialcontainer{
  width:270px;
  padding-top:35%;
  left:80%;
  //position:sticky;
  //text-align:center;
  //border-style: solid;
  //border-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
.socials{
  width:50px;
  float:left;
  display:inline; 
  text-align:center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}

A:not(img){
  color: inherit; /* blue colors for links too */
  text-decoration: inherit; /* no underline */
}

/*a img{
  width:inherit;
  margin:inherit;
  padding:inherit;
  display:inherit;

}*/

a:not(img):hover {
  color: #7d0505;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The simply fix is to float a tag so all direct children will have the same properties

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` tags are `display: inline;` by default. Change the `<a>` tags' that contain your icons display property to `display: inline-block;`